# Export into MS-Word using PHP

Tags: php, ms-word

I want to export data to MS Word file using PHP on Windows and Linux operating system. I have written following code.

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");

echo "<html>";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
echo "<body>";
echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">';
echo '<tr><td>test data</td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

I have the MS Word file properly without table border when opened with MS Office 2007. But, if I open it with MS Office 2003 then I have the MS Word file with table border = '1'.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I have tried it by adding 'style="border:0"'. But, no any fruitful output.

Comment: if you're using sytles, then the correct format would be `style="border-width:0"`

Comment: I have tried above format. But no any fruitful output.

Answer (score 0):

You are indicating via HTTP headers that you're sending a word document (mime type applciation/vnd-ms-word), however you're actually outputting HTML into that document.  If you open the resulting .doc file in a text editor (notepad is a reasonable choice), you'll see that it's actually an HTML file named as .doc. Word can parse this, but the possibilities for formatting are very limited - it doesn't understand everything that a proper web browser would understand.

Instead, you would need to actually convert your output to word document format.  I wouldn't recommend doing this by hand.  If you're running on Windows, you can use COM to create the document.  On linux you're out of luck and would need to use a third-party library.  Have a look at the Zend LiveDocx Framework: http://www.phplivedocx.org/articles/brief-introduction-to-phplivedocx/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have read that article. It is very good article. Above functionality is very small part of my whole project. So, it is hard to include Zend framework for above functionality.